# Alexa sending SMS text Messages

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, sms, alexa-skills-kit

I am looking for any sort of iPhone function for sending messages that can be accessed by an Alexa skill that is able to send SMS text messages, as well as read SMS text messages of a user. I know that these skills are already present, however, I am looking to do this in combination with numerous other features which I have already finished.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex Skills normally run as Amazon Lambda functions. Lambda functions can call other AWS services (from the cloud, not from the phone).

Amazon SNS can send an SMS message. Here is an example using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws sns publish --phone-number +XXXX --message "Hello!"
```

However, if you are looking to send messages from the phone itself, or read messages that are already on the phone, then you will need to write an iPhone app than can use the iOS APIs to send/receive messages. This would not, however, be an 'Alex Skill' since it is running on the phone.

Comment: how can I do this from within the lambda function? What is the response using the response builder?

Comment: @user1366265 Please start a new question rather than asking a question as a comment on an old, existing question.